# How to run to breakpoint in xdebug in sublime text 2 (without adjusting the xdebug URL settings)?

Tags: php, sublimetext2, xdebug

I have xdebug installed and working sublime text 2 and PHP 5.3.26 on OS X 10.8.5. I am able to set a breakpoint and "start debugging." I am able to run to a breakpoint by adjusting the settings in the xdebug menu, going to `settings-default` and adjusting the json to tell xdebug to automatically open a browser that opens the URL of the file I have open in sublime text.

But how do I run to a breakpoint without opening up the menus and changing the settings? I don't want to go fiddle with the internal xdebug settings every time I run a new file.

The docs say to open the "[debugger control menu](https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug)" but I don't know where that is or how to open it. Where do I click? How do I run to a breakpoint without adjusting the menu? [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the shortcut

**Ctrl+Shift+f5:**

> Run to next breakpoint

More information can be gathered here:

https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug